# How to publish data as Dictionary with type Any in pubnub with swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, pubnub

I am using pubnub sdk for socket stuff. My problem is I want to send the data dictionary format with type any but while I am trying to do so the compiler is saying like: **Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'JSONCodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols**. If I am sending with same type data then it is allowing. So how can send the data in dictionary with type Any.

```
var params = [String : Any]()
    
params["isContinous"] = true
params["pressure"] = 1
params["reset"] = true

params["StrokeWidth"] = 11.0

pubnub.publish(channel: "ch:broadcastPoints", message: params) { result in
    switch result {
    case let .success(response):
    print("Successful Publish Response: \(response)")
    case let .failure(error):
    print("Failed Publish Response: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `[String: AnyObject]`?

Comment: no.............let me check

Comment: by using AnyObjetct it also throwning error as AnyObject' cannot be used as a type conforming to protocol 'JSONCodable' because 'JSONCodable' has static requirements

Comment: Create a struct which conforms to `JSONCodable`: `struct Custom: JSONCodable { let isContinous: Bool; let pressure: Int; let reset: Bool; let StrokeWidth: Double }` and use that one. `let params = Custom(isContinous: true, pressure: 1, reset: true, strokeWidth: 11.0)`.

Comment: or maybe try `[String: JSONCodable]`

Answer (score 1):

## Publishing Message Using PubNub Swift SDK

Here are some code samples of how you can publish a message:  https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/swift/api-reference/publish-and-subscribe#publish-a-dictionary-object

If you're trying to do `[String: Any]`, then you won’t be able to do that directly. You could pass that into our `AnyJSON` object, like:
`AnyJSON(yourDictionary)`

But you should really be using custom objects instead of `Any`, so that you can rely on *type safety*.

Comment: Did this work for you?